# Thermal energy into mechanical energy in a car

Tags: energy

Imagine a gasoline gar where heat from burning gasoline is converted
to mechanical energy in a car. We know that some heat is dissipated
by the radiator and exhaust. Is it not possible to capture this heat,
and somehow get it ``back'' to the piston to get converetd to mechanical
energy again by using, say, outside wind?

Comment: "...somehow get it ``back'' to the piston."     How can we do that?

Comment: Note that it is possible to eliminate the radiator, run a ceramic engine at a very high temperature, and get higher efficiency (aka more MPG).  Unfortunately, ceramic engines crumble quickly when exposed to thermal shock, such as that experienced when starting a cold engine.  Thus, while it is possible to use this method, it is impractical and costly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you can imagine some way to convert heat into useful energy by means of, e.g. thermoelectric element. However you should notice that by doing so, this will cause a reduction in the efficiency your primary engine.

This can be seen most easily when you think about Carnot cycle: to maximize your efficiency you want to take heat from a source as hot as possible, and dump into a bath as cold as possible. Interfering with this heat removal step will impair the efficiency of the engine.

So if your engine is well designed, it is already making as much work as possible from the existing heat flow from the heat source (hot gas in the cylinder) to the sink (atmosphere). If your (let's say) thermo-electric element is more efficient than the engine at doing so, then you should remove the engine altogether and use your element as the sole source of work.

P.S. If you notice, the Waste Heart Recovery Units are typically used when heat was produced not by some heat-to-work type device like an engine, but rather in places where heat was produced for other purposes, such as steel mill etc. In this case, the heat is indeed just wasted, and it is a great idea to make some us of it.

Comment: Could you please explain " to maximize your efficiency you want to take heat from a source as hot as possible, and dump into a bath as cold as possible." Why do temperature differentials present an opportunity to generate mechanical energy?

Comment: It is the subject of the Second Law of thermodynamics. When designing an engine, you want to produce as little extra heat as possible. Or, in other words, to produce as little entropy as possible. For this you have no choice but to take "cheaper" heat (from entropy perspective) from a hotter reservoir, and dump less "expensive" heat into colder reservoir. The difference can be used as clean work. This puts a fundamental limit on the efficiency of heat engines (check Carnot cycle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_heat_engine) .

Answer (score 2):

> Is it not possible to capture this heat, and somehow get it ``back'' to the piston to get converetd to mechanical energy again by using, say, outside wind?

Yes, it is possible. Such a device is called a [waste heat recovery unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waste_heat_recovery_unit).

Of course, the WHRU is limited by the same laws of thermodynamics as the engine, meaning that the maximum amount of work $W$ per unit heat $Q$ is $$\frac{W}{Q}=1-\frac{T_H}{T_C}$$

so generally less energy will be extracted since the temperature difference between the hot reservoir, $T_H$, and the cold reservoir, $T_C$, is smaller for the WHRU than from the engine. I.e. the engine runs between the temperature of the ignited fuel and the exhaust while the WHRU runs between the temperature of the exhaust and the environment, which is a much smaller difference and therefore a much lower amount of work extracted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please explain the last statement "so generally less energy will be extracted since the temperature difference between the hot reservoir and the cold reservoir is smaller"? Apologies- I am a total beginner to physics.

Comment: @KwameBrown certainly, I added an extra paragraph of explanation

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. One common way to put the hot exhaust to work is by passing it through a turbine connected to an air compressor, which feeds compressed air into the carburetor or fuel injection system. This is called a *turbocharger* or *power recovery turbine* and is used to boost the power output of the engine.